# Scaffold to dropdown list with C# EF4 - code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, scaffolding

I'm using C#.NET, Entity Framework 4.1 and the code first approach. From that i have a bunch of `entities` and one `entity` is related to another `entity`. They have a primary key/foreign key relation.

I'm also using `ViewModels` to specify which attributes may be scaffolded and i was hoping that the two related entities would create a dropdown list. But that's not happening.

This is just an example of how my entity relation looks, to illustrate my problem.

**UserType entity:**

```
public class UserType
{
    public int UserTypeID { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

**User entity:**

```
public class User
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public int UserTypeID
    public string Username { get; set; }

    public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }

    public virtual UserType UserType { get; set; }
}
```

**My ViewModel:**

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization = MemberSerialization.OptOut, IsReference = false)]
[DataContract]
public class UserViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    public int UserTypeID { get; set; }

    [required]
    public string Username { get; set; }
}
```

So the `UserViewModel` is scaffolded. And i want it to create a dropdown list for the `UserType`. But right now it only creates an `input` field for `UserTypeID`. How can i make it show a dropdown list with the values of `UserTypes`?

Answer (score 0):

The scaffolder has no idea that UserTypeId in your view model relates to an actual UserType class, and therefore has no way of knwoing where to get the static list of user types from.
If you look at the example you referenced, it also includes a navigation property to the foreign key class.

Comment: What navigation property do you mean? I was actually hoping i could tell it somehow that `UserTypeID` is related to another class by using some type of property or annotation. But you're saying thats not possible by just doing something like that?